# Image is not passing to view (cropperjs, django, ajax)

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms, cropperjs

I have an user profile where he can crop his image, and so after cropping, and printing data in view nothing is passed to view
Form

```
 <form method="post" action="change_photo/" id="avatar_changing_form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="upload_image">
                    {% if item.image%}
                    <img src="{{item.image.url}}" alt="" style="max-height:300px">
                    {%else%}
                    <img src="{%static 'avatar_sample.png' %}" id="uploaded_image"
                        class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    {%endif%}
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text">Click to Change Profile Image</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <input type="file" name="image" class="image" id="upload_image" style="display:none" /> -->
                    {{imageForm.image}}
                </label>
            </form>
```

JS & Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  const imageForm = document.getElementById('avatar_changing_form')
    const confirmBtn = document.getElementById('crop')
    const input = document.getElementById('upload_image')
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')


    var $modal = $('#modal');

    var image = document.getElementById('sample_image');

    var cropper;

    $('#upload_image').change(function (event) {
                        var files = event.target.files;

                        var done = function (url) {
                            image.src = url;
                            $modal.modal('show');
                        };

                        if (files && files.length > 0) {
                            reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (event) {
                                done(reader.result);
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                        }
                    });

                    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            viewMode: 3,
                            preview: '.preview'
                        });
                    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                        cropper.destroy();
                        cropper = null;
                    });

                    $('#crop').click(function () {
                        cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob) => {
                            console.log('confirmed')
                            const fd = new FormData();
                            fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf[0].value)
                            fd.append('file', blob, 'my-image.png');

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: imageForm.action,
                                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                                data: fd,
                                success: function (response) {
                                    console.log('success', response)
                                    $modal.modal('hide');
                                    $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', fd);
                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    console.log('error', error)
                                },
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                            })
                        });
                    });
})
```

View

```
def change_photo(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and Guide.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
        item = Guide.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if request.method == "POST":
            Photoform = ChangeImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = item)
            if Photoform.is_valid():
                print(Photoform.cleaned_data['image'])
                Photoform.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

form

```
class ChangeImageForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Guide
    fields = ['image']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChangeImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['image'].widget = FileInput(attrs={
        'name':'image',
        'class':'image',
        'id':'upload_image',
        'style':'display:none'
    })
```

When i print image field from cleaned data in terminal displays "none", and when i load image through admin everything working good, can pls someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: `fd.append('file', blob, 'my-image.png');`  - I guess you stored cropped image(blob) inside `file` so try to print it in views like `print(request.FILES['file'])` and insert it right after `if request.method == "POST":` line.

Comment: @coderasha omg it's working, thank you so much